# How to update the url with ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, url, get

I am currently trying to output a number of records through pages. However I am already kinda failing at the beginning...

The `<table>` with all the records gets updated through ajax. However the problem I have is that whenever I click on the link which should update the `part.php?page=1` it doesn't do anything.

file `part.php`

```
function activateEMode(aa){
//update all val etc
loadDoc("partB.php?page=1"+val+"&person="+person+"&status="+status+"&s_priortiy="+val1+"&s_uDate="+val2+"&s_fDate="+val3+"&search="+search+"&aa="+aa+"&q="+val, partiB);
}
```

file `partB.php`

```
$page = $_GET['page'];

for ($i=1;$i<5;$i++){

        echo '<a href=part.php?page='.$i.'>'.$i.'</a>';
    }
echo $page;
```

So what I am trying to achieve is that, when ajax function loadDoc is called it should set the `?page` to the `<a>` pressed. Would be nice if you could help me :).

Comment: data is incomplete. `loadDoc` function is required. Also where do you want this change to take place- `part.php?page=1`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `window.location.replace` to jump to a new link.

It will be like this:

```
var currnet_Location = windows.location;
var current_Location = current_Location.substring(0, current_Location.indexOf("page="));
var location_to_jump = current_Location+"New Location";
window.location.replace(location_to_jump);
```

Good Luck :)